# How to upload a saved file in django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

In my case, the user gives a word in the front-end and in the back-end, I will call some function that I wrote and at the end, I will build a .PDF file in the `/media/reports` directory.
How I can make these files user-specific and save them in the database?

Before that, I implemented my code without models and forms and just save the file in the `/media/reports/` directory. and the user just could download that file at the moment after being redirected to the download page.

But now, I want to save these files to the database that each user will access new files in his profile. How can I do that ?
Here is my code:

`views.py:`

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def dothat(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'app/dothat.html')

    else:
        try:
            global word, user_name, function_name
            function_name = dothat.__name__
            word = request.POST.get("word")
            user_name = request.user
            full_name = request.user.get_full_name()
            myscript.script_one(word, user_name,full_name, function_name)
            

            # And in the called myscript, after doing some things,
            # the PDF file will be saved in /media/reports/ directory  



        except ValueError:
            return render(request, 'app/dashboard.html', {'error':'Bad data passed in. Try again.'})


    # And then, the user will be redirected to the download page to download that single file

    return render(request, 'app/download.html')
```

and the `download_file` function inside `views.py`

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def download_file(request):
    filename = f"{function_name}-{word}.pdf"
    # Define the full file path
    filepath = f"{BASE_DIR}/app/media/app/reports/{user_name}/{filename}"
    # Open the file for reading content
    if os.path.exists(filepath):
        # Set the return value of the HttpResponse
        response = HttpResponse(open(filepath, 'rb'))
    # Set the HTTP header for sending to browser
        response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" % filename
        return response
    # Return the response value
    else:
        raise HTTP404
```

here is `models.py` Which is based on my new need and I'm not sure it's true or not:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


    class Report(models.Model):
        word = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        title = models.CharField(max_length=100) # i want this title be the file name that i built in the dothat() function.

        report_file = models.FileField(upload_to='reports/%Y/%m/%d')
        report_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

`forms.py`

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Report
from django import forms


class IpscanForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Report
        fields = ['word'] # user just enter the word
```

I want to implement the user single input in the forms and in the models, to save the file processed at the backend in the database and collect all user-specific files to show them to the user on the download-section page. I just don't know how to connect these things together. Do you have any idea that can helps me?

Comment: Hey, just want to clarify, you are asking how can you query all reports of a particular user and show it in his profile right?

Comment: @Girik1105 yes. at current situation i didn't save anything in the database. i just save(write)  the files in a directory that user just can access at that moment to the last report. i want to add this option: every user can see his reports.

Comment: you can use the model where u save the user's pk with the report so he can access his or her reports. The reports which u just wrote to the database before cannot be queried as we have no data on them as to who posted them. Should I write the code as to how u can query a person's reports on his profile?

Comment: @Girik1105 Thank you. I wrote everything i know (i posted my model.py and my forms.py that does not implemented yet.) but i don't know how to work with them in this situation. if you can, please help me more and write the code

Comment: are you using django-rest-framework or only django?

Comment: @Girik1105 I'm using Django

Answer (score 1):

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def user_reports(request):
   user_reports = models.Report.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
   return render(request, 'yourhtmlfile.html', {'user_reports':user_reports})
```

This will allow you to show all the reports of the user who sends a request. Basically, we filter the report model with the requesting user and get all the reports that match the owner user's pk.

Comment: Thank you.  Does my forms.py is True? because i want to reuse this form at another functions too and i don't know where to use that.  and what about the "title", "report_file", "report_date " ? where i should use them? does models.FileField is useful in my case?

Comment: so see you can use the modelform with view that creates these reports. This view will only show the views.